# Error when trying to format a DVD on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, dvd, formatting

I have a DVD that I am trying to format. I'm getting an error that says 'The format did not complete successfully.' when trying to format it in Disk Management and `DiskPart has encountered an error: The parameter is incorrect.
See the System Event Log for more information.` when selecting the volume and running the `format fs=fat32` command in diskpart. It says that the file system is CDFS.

Comment: One usually does not format a blank DVD -- most often, all files are written and then the file system is closed to allow it to be read on other PC's.

Comment: Its not blank I used it as an ubuntu dvd

Comment: Then, AFAIK, it cannot be reformatted.

Comment: What kind of DVD are you trying to format?  A DVD-R (or DVD+R) is only write once. If the disc isn't full, you can add more data to it (until it's finalized), but you can't overwrite existing data.  Only a DVD-RW (or DVD+RW) is rewritable multiple times.